# Create player (which doesn't play file)

Tags: java, javafx, video, media-player, media

I have a class that create video player (code is attached below), this class work only with video file. I want to show the player without a video file, and when I send to the object, by public method "`setFile`", it's will start to play.

I tried to send "null", instead of a file to this class, but I got an error ("`java.lang.NullPointerException`").

```
VideoPlayer player = new VideoPlayer(null, videoWidth, videoHeight);
```

And the error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1323468230.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == ''
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at v04.VideoPlayer.setFile(VideoPlayer.java:90)
    at v04.VideoPlayer.<init>(VideoPlayer.java:40)
    at v04.MainFrame.setVideoPlayer(MainFrame.java:218)
    at v04.MainFrame.createVideoPane(MainFrame.java:246)
    at v04.MainFrame.start(MainFrame.java:112)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$54/539248128.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/1850153616.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also I tried create `Media` without file: (same error)

```
media = new Media(videoFile.toURI().toString());
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(null);
mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
```

**The Class:**

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class VideoPlayer extends GridPane  {

    File videoFile;
    Media media;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    MediaView mediaView;

    DoubleProperty width;
    DoubleProperty height;

    VideoPlayer(File file, double width, double height) {

        setHgap(10);
        setVgap(10);
        setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        setFile(file);
        mediaView.setFitHeight(height*0.80);
        mediaView.setFitWidth(width*0.80);
        mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);


        add(mediaView, 1, 0); 
        add(setSlider(),1,1);

    }

    public HBox setSlider() {

        // Play and pause button
        Button playButton = new Button("Play");
        playButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (playButton.getText().equals("Play")) {
                mediaPlayer.play();
                playButton.setText("pause");
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                playButton.setText("Play");
            }
        });


        // Rewind button
        Button rewindButton = new Button("rewind");
        rewindButton.setOnAction(e -> mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.ZERO));

        // Slieder for volume
        Slider slVolume = new Slider();
        slVolume.setPrefWidth(150);
        slVolume.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        slVolume.setMinWidth(30);
        slVolume.setValue(50);
        mediaPlayer.volumeProperty().bind(slVolume.valueProperty().divide(100));
        HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(playButton, rewindButton,
                new Label("Volume"), slVolume);
        return hBox;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {

        videoFile=file;
        videoFile = file;
        media = new Media(videoFile.toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        width = mediaView.fitWidthProperty();
        height = mediaView.fitHeightProperty();
    }

    public void playVideo() {
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to your English issues (of which I mean no offense), I cannot understand what you are asking. Can you try to re-phrase this better so I can understand?

Comment: @Water  I want run this class without video-file (only show the player!). This is possible? Or make a frame to the player...

Comment: Can you post your null pointer stack trace and/or tell me what the offending lines are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a null argument to your constructor's first arg, this is passed to setFile as this: `setFile(null)`

This function has:

```
public void setFile(File file) {
    videoFile = file;
    videoFile = file; // You are doing this twice? Is this an error on your part?
    media = new Media(videoFile.toURI().toString()); // This is where the null pointer is happening.
}
```

videoFile is null, and you are calling `toURI()` on a null object.

I do not know if this will fully solve your issue, but unless you change your code -- you need to guard against nulls like so:

```
public void setFile(File file) {
    if (file == null)
        return;
    videoFile = file;
    media = new Media(videoFile.toURI().toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    width = mediaView.fitWidthProperty();
    height = mediaView.fitHeightProperty();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I  think you don't understand what I mean. I know what is causing this  error, I did it to test. Anyway, I solved it by a black rectangle that appears when a video file is null. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't have been of more help, glad you fixed it anyways though!