# Video doesn't start

Tags: javafx, video, media-player, media

I am beginner in Java. I am trying to create a video player with JavaFX, but after running the code, the video won't start. The console, however, is showing no errors.

This is the code:

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

public class Player extends BorderPane {

Media media;
MediaPlayer player;
MediaView view;
Pane mpane;

public Player(String file){

    if (file == null)
        return;
    media = new Media(file);
    player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    view = new MediaView(player);
    mpane = new Pane();

    mpane.getChildren().add(view);      
    setCenter(mpane);       
    player.play();

    }   
}
```

Main class:

```
    package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Player player = new Player("file:///D:/2013.flv");
        Scene scene = new Scene(player, 720, 480, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why do you have a return statement in your constructor? Might it be that the passed in file is null and the rest of the constructor is not executed? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: In most cases a `IllegalArgumentException` should be thrown, if the parameter value is invalid. BTW: I've tried the code out (`new Player(new File("path/to/myVideoFile.mp4").toURI().toString())`) and I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: @hotzst the return statement was added when I found this answer at a similar question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415651/javafx-create-player-which-doesnt-play-file. With, or without, it doesnt changes anything.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. This makes it easier for people to debug and offer a solution to your question.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha edited the post adding the main class.

Comment: It's possible the video in your FLV file is not a supported format. Try passing the URL `"http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv"` (which is the sample from the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/simpleplayer.htm)). If that doesn't work, something is wrong in your code. If it does, it's likely your video is not a supported format. Some details about supported formats are listed on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm#JFXMD101

Comment: Thank you James_D, it does start using your link, although its the same file extension as what I previously had-'.flv'. 
Now I have to work on window, because the video starts in a smaller size than playing the video in browse.